# Terraform -var-file not working for file present in the same directory

Tags: terraform

I am trying to pass file name as command Line argument and following the examples i found on internet. following is the command i am using :

terraform plan -var-file=cert.tf

and get the following error:

invalid value "cert" for flag -var-file: Error reading cert: open cert: The system cannot find the file specified

Cert.tf is present in the same path where i am executing the command. Has anyone else experienced this ?

Comment: Have you tried terraform plan -var-file="./cert.tf"?

Comment: I got the following error :invalid value "./cert.tf" for flag -var-file: multiple map declarations not supported for variables

Comment: Looks like the issue is for windows .. I am trying this on Power shell .

Comment: I'm using windows myself and this is how I do it. Are you using Terraform .8? They changed some formatting stuff in .8 that might be causing the problem.

Comment: No i was on 0.7.3 . I just upgraded .. Behavior is still the same

Comment: Can you post the contents of your cert.tf file (without the real cert, of course)? Also, if you're just trying to import a cert, I do it this way:

ssh_key = "${file("../credentials/my_cert_file")}"

Comment: For example : variable "user_label" {
  default = "Test"
}
variable "count" {
  default = 3
} ... I would like to have multiple files with same variables which i can use the way i want

Comment: My aim is to create files for different environments

Comment: I notice that the official docs all reference a .tfvars file (this is what I do as well). Have you tried that file extension?

Comment: yeah i see that too . So the variable file i want to send as argument should have .tfvars extension . Is that correct ?

Comment: It's worth a try! Let me know if it works out.

Comment: @user3482804 yes that should be exactly it. Terraform will only look for vars in tfvars files. By default this is `terraform.tfvars` but you can also create other tfvars files and then use `-var-file=path/to/vars.tfvars` as you were trying in the question. If that has worked for you then @mcheshier might want to post it as an answer (considering he spotted the problem).

Answer (score 2):

Your variables file needs to have the .tfvars extension.

Comment: For me even though its name is correct and its extension is `.tfvars` it yields at me that `Error: Failed to read variables file` and `Given variables file ./deployment/shared.tfvars does not exist.`. Please note that the file exits in that path and I even tried absolute path but no luck